# Apache Flink: Windowed ReduceFunction is never executed

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

below is code snippet, where I'm using a Tumbling EventTime based window

```
DataStream<OHLC> ohlcStream = stockStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TimestampExtractor()).map(new mapStockToOhlc()).keyBy((KeySelector<OHLC, Long>) o -> o.getMinuteKey())
        .timeWindow(Time.seconds(60))
        .reduce(new myAggFunction());
```

Unfortunatelly, it looks like it never exectutes the reduce function. If use code above w/o windowing, reduce function works fine. Below is code for TimestampExtractor. The 30 seconds watermark delay serves just as a testing value, but the one minute tumbling window is m

```
    public static class TimestampExtractor implements AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<StockTrade> {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
        return new Watermark(System.currentTimeMillis() - 30000);
    }

    @Override
    public long extractTimestamp(StockTrade stockTrade, long l) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(stockTrade.getTime());
        // bd contains miliseconds timestamp 1498658629.036
        return bd.longValue();
    }
}
```

bd.longValue() which returns seconds timestamp 1498658629, as my window is defined also in seconds.
When I used bd.longValue()/60, which returns minute timestamp, reduce function is called. My output file than contains all records for each reduce operation

```
{time=1498717692.000, minuteTime=24978628, n=1, open=2248.0}
{time=1498717692.000, minuteTime=24978628, n=2, open=2248.0}
...
{time=1498717692.000, minuteTime=24978628, n=8, open=2248.0}
```

So, can anyone explain to me, what is happening? Thx a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Normally watermarks should be relative to the timestamps in your data, and should not be based on the system clock. One of the great things about working with event time is that the same application can be used to reprocess historic data or to process current data, but that's not possible if you compare your timestamps to the the system clock, as you've done here.

A watermark can be thought of as a statement that all data with timestamps smaller than the watermark have already arrived. Or in other words, any data with a timestamp less than the current watermark will be considered late. My guess is that you are not seeing any results because your watermarks are causing all of your data to be considered late, and the window operator is dropping all this late data.

I suggest you use a [BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/event_timestamp_extractors.html#assigners-allowing-a-fixed-amount-of-lateness) instead. It works by keeping track of the max timestamp seen so far in the data stream, and subtracts the delay from that max timestamp, rather than the system clock. The [source code](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/timestamps/BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor.java#L72), in case you're curious.

Comment: Thx, I'll look into it. Actually I used examples all over the internet, e.g. http://vishnuviswanath.com/flink_eventtime.html ... Also my data contains arrival time into the cluster (which is usually few miliseconds later than the EventTime), and it seems the Flink process takes care of quick. So 90 seconds should be enough...

Comment: I took a look on a doc and a source code. I used something similar in my own. Even if the time amout might be enough, you are right, this enables to process historical data. Actually, we had to reboot the cluster, so Kafka topic is still idle, so I verified processing historical data saved in the Kafka topic. Reduce function is called and it saves only the last (probably? - is it possible? Seems  logical tho.) result in the defined window + watermark delay. I have to investigate more and compare results. Once I verify corectness of results, I'll mark topic as solved.

Comment: Watermarks that are relative to the system clock can appear to work, but are problematic, even if you only care about processing real-time data. This is because if a job fails and is then rolled back to a checkpoint and restarted, the data being replayed is likely to be deemed late.

Comment: And yes, a windowed reduce function incrementally aggregates the contents of the window, producing a single value when the window is triggered.